# Change objectForKey value on each button click

Tags: ios, objective-c, button, nsdictionary, plist

I am downloading a key from plist to my array on button click, like this:

```
- (IBAction)nextKey:(id)sender {

NSString *mainBundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSString *plistPath = [mainBundlePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"text.plist"];
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary new] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
wordsArray = [dict objectForKey:@"key1"];

}
```

I need change key value to the next from plist on each button click.

How i can do this?

Comment: Please explain your problem

Comment: Did my solution work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an NSArray in your class. And keyvalue in it.Also add a int variable.Like

```
NSArray *arrKey = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Key1",@"Key2",@"Key3",@"Key4",@"Key5", nil];
int flagKey = 0;
- (IBAction)nextKey:(id)sender {

  NSString *mainBundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
  NSString *plistPath = [mainBundlePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"text.plist"];
  NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary new] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
  wordsArray = [dict objectForKey:[arrKey objectAtIndex:flagKey]];
  if(flagKey < arrKey.count-1){
    flagkey++;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain a count and each time when button pressed , increase the count like

```
-(IBAction)nextKey:(id)sender {
    NSString *mainBundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    NSString *plistPath = [mainBundlePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"text.plist"];
    NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary new] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
    wordsArray = [dict objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"key%d",index]];
    index++;
}
```

Or you can set the button tag, and alter it every time when you press Button. Set initially it to 0 or starting key name in your plist file

```
-(IBAction)nextKey:(id)sender {
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    NSString *mainBundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    NSString *plistPath = [mainBundlePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"text.plist"];
    NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary new] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
    wordsArray = [dict objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"key%d",button.tag]];
    button.tag = button.tag + 1;
}
```

Comment: Good solution with "button.tag".
Thank you for help.

Comment: this solution is working if the key is in series key. if the Key's are @"Sam",@"Display",@"Text",@"Wrong",@"Phase" etc then it not work